rendering parameters of the DatabricksWorkflowTaskGroup
My understanding is that the DatabricksWorkflowTaskGroup is inheriting from a TaskGroup which doesn't perform template rendering,
The branch name is defined in my variables json files, one for staging and one for production.
I'm not sure what's the best option for me in this case.
task_group = DatabricksWorkflowTaskGroup(
        group_id="test",
        databricks_conn_id=dbx_connection_id,
        job_clusters=job_cluster_spec,
        extra_job_params={
            "git_source": {
                "git_url": "",
                "git_provider": "{{ var.json.git_provider }}",
                "git_branch": "{{ var.json.git_branch }}",
            },
        },
    )


Sorry, the question is not clear. Can you please elaborate on the question?

I meant, because the DatabricksWorkflowTaskGroup is inheriting from a TaskGroup which isn't performing template variables rendering, how can I pass a dynamic set of parameters such as git branch which changes depending on the environment, usually we define a staging.json and prod.json and have different values there
